# the Component of my classes always get reinitialized

Tags: javascript, reactjs

sorry if the question is bad, i'm a total begginer at react.

i was trying to make a dashboard, but my states always get reinitialized.
here is the content of my app.js.

```
import './index.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, PureComponent, Component } from 'react';

class WidgetStatus extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.intef = 0;
    this.state = {
      "4766":0,
      "4767":0,
      "4768":0,
      "4769":0,
      "4770":0,
      "4771":0,
    };
  }
  setPOLState(Num, choice) {
    this.intef += 1;
    this.setState(previousState => ({[Num]: this.previousState[Num] + choice}));
  }
  render(Num) {
    if (this.state[Num] == 0) {
      return (
        <div>
          test
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.state[Num] == 1) {
      return (
      <div>
        You chose one
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.state[Num] == 2) {
      return (
      <div>
        You chose two
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.state[Num] == 3) {
      return (
      <div>
        You chose three
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.state[Num] == 4) {
      return (
      <div>
        You chose four
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.state[Num] == 5) {
      return (
      <div>
        You chose five
        </div>
      );
    } else if (this.state[Num] == 6) {
      return (
      <div>
        You chose six
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
};

const statwid = new WidgetStatus();

function App() {

  let machin = 1;
  statwid.setPOLState("4771", 1);
  
  function Dropitemclick(numNav, numitem) {
      function handleclick(numNav, numitem) {
        statwid.setPOLState(numNav, numitem);
        }
      handleclick(numNav, numitem);
      }

  function App2() {
    machin += 1;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Navbar>
          <NavItem icon={"Choice"}>
            <DropdownMenu number={"4766"}></DropdownMenu>
          </NavItem>
        </Navbar>
          <div>{statwid.render("4766")}</div>
        <Navbar>
          <NavItem icon={"Choice"}>
            <DropdownMenu number={"4767"}></DropdownMenu>
          </NavItem>
        </Navbar>
        <div>{statwid.render("4767")}</div>
        <Navbar>
          <NavItem icon={"Choice"}>
            <DropdownMenu number={"4768"}></DropdownMenu>
          </NavItem>
        </Navbar>
        <div>{machin + 1}</div>
        <Navbar>
          <NavItem icon={"Choice"}>
            <DropdownMenu number={"4769"}></DropdownMenu>
          </NavItem>
        </Navbar>
        <div>{statwid.render("4769")}</div>
        <Navbar>
          <NavItem icon={"Choice"}>
            <DropdownMenu number={"4770"}></DropdownMenu>
          </NavItem>
        </Navbar>
        <div>{statwid.render("4770")}</div>
        <Navbar>
          <NavItem icon={"Choice"}>
            <DropdownMenu number={"4771"}></DropdownMenu>
          </NavItem>
        </Navbar>
        <div>{statwid.render("4771")}</div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  function Navbar(props) {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar">
        <ul className="navbar-nav">{props.children}</ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }

  function NavItem(props) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    return (
      <li className="nav-item">
        <a href="#" className="icon-button" onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}>
          {props.icon}
        </a>

        {open && props.children}
      </li>
    );
  }

  function DropdownMenu(props) {
    function DropdownItem(props) {
      return (
        <a href="#" className="menu-item">
          <span className="icon-button">{props.leftIcon}</span>
          {props.children}
        </a>
      );
    }

    return (
      <div className="dropdown">
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 0)}>N/A Service</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 1)}>Time Service</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 2)}>Youtube Service</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 3)}>weather Service</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 4)}>Reddit Service</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 5)}>Reddit2 Service</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 6)}>Reddit3 Service</DropdownItem>
      </div>
    );
  }
 return (App2());
}


export default App;
```

as you can see, i tried various things to see if i could change them, according to how i planned this i expected that when clicking on the button "Time widget" i would modify the state and print.

sadly it doesn't do anything.
here is the content of my index.js just in case.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more:
reportWebVitals();
```

i'm sure it is something dumb but i'm stuck and don't know how to procede.

Edit: i found out it was possibly because of the render, but i don't know how to fix that
Edit2: just in case, i'll add my .css

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #151616;
  font-family: roboto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

code {
  font-family: source-code-pro, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, 'Courier New',
    monospace;
}


:root {
  --bg:  #242526;
  --bg-accent: #484a4d;
  --text-color: #dadce1;
  --nav-size: 280px;
  --border: 1px solid #474a4d;
  --border-radius: 8px;
  --speed: 500ms;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: var(--text-color);
  text-decoration: none;;
}
```

after more test, it seem that either the display isn't changing (but clicking on the buttons has a visual effect so not probable) or indeed the class always reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the `class WidgetStatus` which should `extend Component` since `WidgetStatus` holds state - as discussed in Ron's answer, you're mutating its state directly:

```js
setState(Num, choice) {
  this.state[Num] += choice;
}
```

Mutating state directly is a big no-no in React.

What you should've done is use `setState()` instead:

```js
setState(Num, choice) {
  this.setState(previousState => ({ [Num]: previousState[Num] + choice }));
}
```

### EDIT

Just noticed the `onClick={Dropitemclick(props.number, [0-6])}` props in the `<DropdownItem />` components. These functions will get called immediately on render, and `Dropitemclick()` does not return an expected function.

`onClick` expects a callback with at most one parameter: `event`. When you click on something with an `onClick` prop, that prop fires the function passed into it with the `event` object. What you're doing now is passing the **calculated value** of each of the `Dropitemclick()` functions on the `onClick` instead of a function.

Try doing this:

```
<DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 0)}>N/A Service</DropdownItem>
<DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 1)}>Time Service</DropdownItem>
<DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 2)}>Youtube Service</DropdownItem>
<DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 3)}>weather Service</DropdownItem>
<DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 4)}>Reddit Service</DropdownItem>
<DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 5)}>Reddit2 Service</DropdownItem>
<DropdownItem onClick={() => Dropitemclick(props.number, 6)}>Reddit3 Service</DropdownItem>
```

### EDIT 2

I made it work, but had to rewrite a lot of code.

1. `DropdownItem`'s `onClick` prop should've passed to the `<a>`, like this:

   ```js
   <a onClick={props.onClick}>
     ...
   </a>
   ```
2. This is **not** how you're supposed to render a component:

   ```js
   const statwid = new WidgetStatus();
   ```

   You're supposed to use it in either a `React.createElement()`, or in JSX. In any case, you're not supposed to call its methods, like `statwid.setPOLState()`.
3. This also makes state management a bit tricky, since you're making changes in the `App` component via the `Dropitemclick()` function but want to change state held in `WidgetStatus`. So I moved the state from the `WidgetStatus` component to the `App` component, since `App` is the common ancestor of both.

   Initialize your state, like so:

   ```js
   const [choices, setChoices] = useState({
    "4766":0,
    "4767":0,
    "4768":0,
    "4769":0,
    "4770":0,
    "4771":0,
   });
   ```

   and every time you want to change one of the state's key-value pairs:

   ```js
   setChoices(prevState => ({
     ...prevState,
     [numNav]: numitem
   }));
   ```
4. Finally, by moving state away from `WidgetStatus` component, we can

   1. make it extend `PureComponent`
   2. delete all its functions except for `render()` - and by the way `render()` should not take any parameters
   3. replace `this.state[Num]` with `this.props.choice` in the if-else statements.

   Finally, in `App2` lines with:

   ```
   <div>{statwid.render("4766")}</div>
   ```

   should be replaced with:

   ```
   <WidgetStatus choice={choices["4766"]} />
   ```

   to pass the appropriate value from the `choices` state to `WidgetStatus`' `choice` prop.

Comment: thanks, sadly it doesn't work either, but i'll try to keep the coding habit

Comment: Thanks once again, but it didn't work either, i'll put the updated version of my code just in case

Answer (score 0):

PureComponent is used when the component shouldn't re-render when the state is changed. If you want your component to re-render based on the state, WidgetStatus should extend Component instead of PureComponent.

Comment: if you mean trying class `WidgetStatus extends Component` it don't seem to work either